# What are the most frequent viewport sizes to use in responsive design?

Tags: responsive-webdesign, media-queries

I see differnt suggestions from very detailed (like [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)) to more brief, like google ([here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html)). so I am wondering what are the most suitable sizes to be used @media screen.

Answer (score 9):

This may not a “stat”, but take a look at Twitter Bootstrap that is starting to be used a lot.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_variables.scss

In short:

- <= 767px
- 768px – 979px
- 980px – 1199px
- > = 1200px

Answer (score 9):

I guess this depends on the design, which might differ each build. It also depends if your using 100% fluid or changing on breakpoints.

I tend to use some of the following, generally the large sizes don't change much at all between breakpoints:

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px){} // mobile portrait
@media screen and (min-width:480px){} // mobile landscape
@media screen and (min-width:768px){} // ipad portrait
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){} // browser, ipad landscape
@media screen and (min-width:1200px){} // browser
@media screen and (min-width:1600px){} // browser
```

No point trying to cover all the different android etc resolutions...there are so many.

Also sometimes the breakpoints don't trigger on the actual size due to the scrollbar, which each browser has different rules for. Might be wise to cut off 20px per @media to make sure they trigger. I sometimes swap the min-width:320px for a max-width: 480px, as under 320 nothing might be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Statcounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/desktop-mobile-tablet/worldwide/#monthly-202109-202209) those are currently (10.2022) the most used monitor sizes:

- 1920x1080 - 8.87%
- 1366x768 - 6.63%
- 360x800 - 5.91%
- 1536x864 - 4.09%
- 414x896 - 3.65%
- 390x844 - 3.6%

Percents are an amount of internet users.